# Removing prepending “0” output from Haskell toBinary function that converts number to binary string?

Tags: haskell, binary

I am new to Haskell. My function is supposed to take an integer and convert it to a string in base 2. My code works correctly, but I would like to remove "0" from my results.

For example, toBinary 16 outputs "010000" rather than "10000", as I would like.

Does anyone have any advice?

```
toBinary :: Integer -> [Char]

toBinary x = if (x == 0) then "0" else toBinary ( div x 2 ) ++ show(mod x 2 )
```

Comment: `dropWhile (== '0')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a helper function that calls your recursive function, as there's only one case in which you want to prepend "0" (when the number is 0).

```hs
toBinary' :: Integer -> String
toBinary' 0 = ""
toBinary' x = toBinary' (div x 2) ++ show (mod x 2)

toBinary :: Integer -> String
toBinary 0 = "0"
toBinary x = toBinary' x
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an additional base case to handle both single-digit values non-recursively:

```
toBinary :: Integer -> String
toBinary 0 = "0"
toBinary 1 = "1"
toBinary x = toBinary (div x 2) ++ show (mod x 2)
```

Since `x` will only match values 2 or greater, the recursive call will never result in `"0"`.